# Windows Server 2019 calling elevated powershell Hyper-V scripts from IIS (c# mvc)

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, model-view-controller

as part of c# mvc application I'm merging hyper-v machines manager, start/stop maybe in future provisioning, however though as I am able to run powershell scripts in their simplest scope I cannot manage to get around the hyper-v cmdlets to work.

I have already tried to add my application pool to Hyper-V Administrators as this is WS2019 and administrators itself and that doesn't seem to work either. Moreover I've tried to create self-elevating ps scripts to get me through, running batch files failed and still nothing. I am using anonymous auth and don't know this might cause some issues, as I'm not so enthusiastic about.

c#
ps.AddScript(scriptPath);
ps.Invoke();

for start I need to be able to manage start/stop in some most elegant way possible. Best practices are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you create a dedicated Windows service application to run the Hyper-V cmdlets.  This service can be configured to run with a proper user account that has sufficient privileges to run the cmdlets.  Your webapp should communicate with this service via WCF.  In this way, you will be able to run your webapp with the default low-privilege account and guarantee the security of your system.